# Suddenly this Python program is not able to fetch data from bseindia API. Any way to debug changes in API and pass proper parametrs?

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-requests

This code has been working for many years. A few years back, I faced similar issues where in there was change in API and I do not remember how I could debug it and see that extra parameter for page number was added.  Now again there seems to be some slight change and my program is not able to fetch data. Any help shall be appreciated.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import sys
import numpy as np
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
pdate ="20230721"               # starting date
date ="20230724"            # till this date
url = 'https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/AnnGetData/w'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'}

payload = {
'Pageno': 1,
'strCat': '-1',
'strPrevDate': pdate,
'strScrip': '',
'strSearch': 'P',
'strToDate':   date,
'strType': 'C'}

data = []
should_fetch_next_page = True
while should_fetch_next_page:
    print(f"Fetching page {payload['Pageno']} ...")
    jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
    if jsonData["Table"]:
        data.extend(jsonData["Table"])
        payload['Pageno'] += 1
        # every thing we want to do

    else:
        should_fetch_next_page = False

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API url changed, also the server need in HTTP header `Referer`:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

pdate = "20230721"  # starting date
date = "20230724"  # till this date
url = "https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/AnnSubCategoryGetData/w"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0",
    "Referer": "https://www.bseindia.com/",
}

payload = {
    "pageno": 1,
    "strCat": "-1",
    "strPrevDate": pdate,
    "strScrip": "",
    "strSearch": "P",
    "strToDate": pdate,
    "strType": "C",
    "subcategory": "",
}

data = []
should_fetch_next_page = True
while should_fetch_next_page:
    print(f"Fetching page {payload['pageno']} ...")
    jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
    if jsonData["Table"]:
        data.extend(jsonData["Table"])
        payload["pageno"] += 1
        # every thing we want to do

    else:
        should_fetch_next_page = False

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
Fetching page 1 ...
Fetching page 2 ...
Fetching page 3 ...

...
```

---

NOTE: To debug the future problems, the base URL for this API request is `https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/ann.html`. So open the URL in your browser and open Web Developer Tools -> Network tab and reload the page.

You should see the API url there + the required parameters/HTTP headers/cookies/etc...

Comment: Yes I did it like this only. but not so conversant and had forgotten. Issue is fully resolved quite fast.